# what does "as you" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I want to congratulate my friend in advance for giving birth to her first baby soon. 
I just want to confirm if this sentence is correct.

"Congratulations in advance as you give birth to your first baby."
or 
can I just use "for".
"Congratulations in advance for giving birth to your first baby."

Do "for" and "as you" there have the same meaning?

Comment: Why not "Congratulations on being pregnant. I wish you........." and then, when baby is born, "Congratulations on the birth of ....."

Comment: No, "for" and "as you" *do not* have the same meaning.

Comment: I would congratulate her *after* the birth. There is never any guarantee that it will go well. How will you feel if she miscarries?

Comment: If you feel it necessary to convey greetings prior to the birth, it would be more appropriate to convey "best wishes" rather than "congratulations".

Answer (score 2):

This might be splitting hairs, but ...

You are congratulating your friend in advance, so I wouldn't say either "as you give birth" or "for giving birth".

"In advance" pertains to the the future, whereas "as you give birth" pertains to the time during which your friend is actually giving birth.

"In advance" pertains to the the future, whereas "for giving birth" implies the birth has already occurred.

Perhaps:

> "Congratulations in advance *on* the birth of your first baby."

I would also consider carefully the thoughtful comments on your question. It's dangerous to congratulate your friend before she has given birth: something could go wrong. You might want to consider one of the following alternatives:

> "Congratulations on your pregnancy."
>
> "Best wishes for the upcoming birth of your first baby."

The advantage of the former is that it focuses only on the present fact of pregnancy. (Of course, something could go wrong there, too.) The advantage of the latter is that it expresses your hope that all will go well without presuming that will be the case.

Comment: I was like "auch" while reading the question but your answer made relieved. Anonymous user, listen to Richard's advice.